# Cypher aggregation and collect

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Given the following result in my cypher query, where people are a collection:

```
[
   {
      "people": [
         {
            "id": 24749,
            "matches": 1
         },
         {
            "id": 26026,
            "matches": 1
         },
         {
            "id": 26223,
            "matches": 1
         },
         {
            "id": 25121,
            "matches": 1
         },
         {
            "id": 24632,
            "matches": 1
         },
         {
            "id": 25708,
            "matches": 1
         },
         {
            "id": 25182,
            "matches": 1
         },
         {
            "id": 24826,
            "matches": 1
         },
         {
            "id": 26186,
            "matches": 1
         },
         {
            "id": 27001,
            "matches": 1
         },
         {
            "id": 24243,
            "matches": 1
         },
         {
            "id": 27255,
            "matches": 1
         },
         {
            "id": 27145,
            "matches": 1
         },
         {
            "id": 24126,
            "matches": 1
         },
         {
            "id": 27463,
            "matches": 1
         },
         {
            "id": 24069,
            "matches": 1
         },
         {
            "id": 25210,
            "matches": 1
         },
         {
            "id": 24994,
            "matches": 1
         },
         {
            "id": 27331,
            "matches": 1
         },
         {
            "id": 25793,
            "matches": 1
         },
         {
            "id": 27312,
            "matches": 1
         },
         {
            "id": 26206,
            "matches": 1
         },
         {
            "id": 24252,
            "matches": 1
         },
         {
            "id": 24714,
            "matches": 2
         },
         {
            "id": 24612,
            "matches": 1
         },
         {
            "id": 26964,
            "matches": 1
         },
         {
            "id": 27101,
            "matches": 1
         },
         {
            "id": 26730,
            "matches": 1
         },
         {
            "id": 27211,
            "matches": 1
         },
         {
            "id": 24783,
            "matches": 2
         },
         {
            "id": 25336,
            "matches": 1
         },
         {
            "id": 24128,
            "matches": 1
         },
         {
            "id": 26186,
            "matches": 1
         },
         {
            "id": 25125,
            "matches": 2
         },
         {
            "id": 24069,
            "matches": 3
         },
         {
            "id": 24607,
            "matches": 1
         },
         {
            "id": 27055,
            "matches": 1
         },
         {
            "id": 25336,
            "matches": 3
         },
         {
            "id": 24128,
            "matches": 2
         },
         {
            "id": 26716,
            "matches": 1
         },
         {
            "id": 27331,
            "matches": 1
         },
         {
            "id": 24069,
            "matches": 1
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

How can I (with cypher) iterate the people collection and find the ones with the same "id", sum the "matches" items together and then add a new item called "duplicates" or similar.

Example result I'm trying to get:

```
[
  {
    "people": [
      {
        "id": 24069,
        "matches": 5,  // all the "matches" of the duplicate 24069's added together
        "duplicates": 3 // how may times the id 24069 was found in the collection called people
      },

      // etc...
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: What is your current cypher query?

Answer (score 0):

The query:

> match (p:people) return distinct(p.id),sum(p.matches)

should probably give you what you need

Answer (score 0):

This is kinda complicated, as the simplest way is to tear your collection apart and reassemble it. It's a lot of steps, but here is the Cypher to do that as well as comments on what each step is doing.

```
// initial matching (whatever you match on to get your collection)
MATCH (n:People) WITH collect(n) as people

// Tear people collection apart for possessing
UNWIND people as p 

// Reduce on id
WITH COLLECT(DISTINCT p.id) as id, p.matches as m

// For each id, sum and count the matches
WITH {id:id, matches:SUM(m), duplicates:COUNT(m)} as people

// Recollect rows into collection
RETURN COLLECT(people) as people
```